# Why lvalue required as increment operand?

Tags: c, post-increment, pre-increment

I know those precedence and associativity at all, but I cant able to sort the error correctly for this expression.

```
c=b|i+++++j;
```

Comment: Don't do weird things, everyone will hate you.

Comment: sorry i'm not doing any weird things,just have gone through some questions.From mistakes only we can learn the concepts exactly. :)

Comment: Well said :) I was just kidding.

Answer (score 1):

Read [Maximum Munch Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_munch)

> > "maximal munch" or "longest match" is the principle that when creating some construct, as much of the available input as possible should be consumed.

---

Every compiler has a tokenizer, which is a component that parses a source file into distinct tokens (keywords, operators, identifiers etc.). One of the tokenizer's rules is called "maximal munch", which says that the tokenizer should keep reading characters from the source file until adding one more character causes the current token to stop making sense.

`++` (postfix) doesnt return an `lvalue` but it requires its operand to be an `lvalue`.